# DigitalOcean Server receiving too many unkown log requests

Tags: security, digital-ocean

When I type '# tail -f /var/log/auth.log' on my digital ocean server,
I receive the following logs and it keep going without stopping.

Jul 10 07:51:58 aaa login[16661]: pam_securetty(login:auth): access denied: tty '/dev/pts/1' is not secure !

Jul 10 07:51:59 aaa login[16663]: FAILED LOGIN (3) on '/dev/pts/0' from '2.159.212.218.starhub.net.sg' FOR 'root', Authentication failure

Jul 10 07:51:59 aaa login[16663]: pam_securetty(login:auth): access denied: tty '/dev/pts/0' is not secure !

Jul 10 07:52:00 aaa login[16665]: FAILED LOGIN (2) on '/dev/pts/3' from 'c-69-142-92-100.hsd1.nj.comcast.net' FOR 'root', Authentication failure

Jul 10 07:52:01 aaa login[16665]: pam_securetty(login:auth): access denied: tty '/dev/pts/3' is not secure !

Jul 10 07:52:01 aaa login[16663]: FAILED LOGIN (4) on '/dev/pts/0' from '2.159.212.218.starhub.net.sg' FOR 'root', Authentication failure

Jul 10 07:52:01 aaa login[16663]: pam_securetty(login:auth): access denied: tty '/dev/pts/0' is not secure !

Jul 10 07:52:01 aaa login[16661]: FAILED LOGIN (4) on '/dev/pts/1' from 'c-73-43-86-218.hsd1.ga.comcast.net' FOR 'root', Authentication failure

Answer (score 2):

That are bots, trying to log into your droplet by brute force.

Consider installing [Fail2Ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to automatically block IPs that fail too many ssh login attempts or, if that's an option, restrict access to port 22 to only trusted IPs (either use [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) or the DigitalOcean Firewall rules).